# Create array with an additional property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm using an existing 3rd party API over which I have no control and which requires me to pass an array with an additional property. Something like the following:

```
type SomeArgument = string[] & { foo: string };
doSomething (argument: SomeArgument);
```

Now I find it quite clumsy and verbose, to create `SomeArgument` while keeping the compiler satisfied.

This one works, but no type safety at all:

```
const customArray: any = ['baz'];
customArray.foo = 'bar';
doSomething(customArray);
```

Another option which feels cleaner, but is quite verbose (I will need different subclasses with different properties) is to subclass `Array`:

```
class SomeArgumentImpl extends Array<string> {
  constructor (public foo: string, content?: Array<string>) {
    super(...content);
  }
}
doSomething(new SomeArgumentImpl('bar', ['baz']));
```

Is there any better, one-liner-style way? I was hoping for something along `doSomething({ ...['baz'], foo: 'bar' });` (this one does not work, obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is the function you want to call:

```
function doSomething (argument: string[] & { foo: string }) {
   argument.push("a");
   argument.foo = "4";
   console.log(argument);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
// Works
doSomething(Object.assign(["a", "b"], { foo: "c" }));
// Error
doSomething(Object.assign(["a", 2], { foo: "c" }));
// Error
doSomething(Object.assign(["a", 2], { foo: 4 }));
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for: `doSomething` is actually a 3rd party library function over which I have no control. I just need to provide an argument of type `string[] & { foo: string }`, which I want to create as simply as possible. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh, I thought you're wrapping the library function with a function of your own. I see the problem now :) -- updated my answer.

Comment: Ahhh, the idea with `Object.assign` didn't come to my mind. Perfect!